# why is this variable not being changed?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a larger script but this smaller one shows the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0
if [[ $x == 0 ]]
then
   ls | while read L
   do
     x=5
     echo "this is a file $L and this is now set to five --> $x"
   done
fi
echo "this should NOT be 0 --> $x"
```

If the variable is set outside the while loop then it works as I expect.
The bash version is 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu). I'll feel so dumb if this is some obvious thing.

Comment: This is a common question. Read faq: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: Another great link: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Check this similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233452/bash-variable-change-doesnt-persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` being set to 5 is in a sub-shell (because it is part of a pipeline), and what happens in a sub-shell does not affect the parent shell.

You can avoid the sub-shell and get the result you expected by using process substitution in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0
if [[ $x == 0 ]]
then
   while read L
   do
     x=5
     echo "this is a file $L and this is now set to five --> $x"
   done < <(ls)
fi
echo "this should NOT be 0 --> $x"
```

Now the `while` loop is part of the main shell process (only the `ls` is in a sub-process) so the variable `x` is affected.

We can discuss the merits of parsing the output of `ls` another time; it is largely incidental to the issue in the question.

Another option would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0
if [[ $x == 0 ]]
then
   ls | 
   {
   while read L
   do
     x=5
     echo "this is a file $L and this is now set to five --> $x"
   done
   echo "this should NOT be 0 --> $x"
   }
fi
echo "this should be 0 still, though --> $x"
```

Comment: Ouch! How embarrasing. Thanks to Aleks-Daniel Jakimenko and Jonathan Leffler.