# bash: associative array - multiple value for one key

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have GIT repository where I have commits and tags. Some commit has 2 or more tags. I would like to create associative array where:

- key = commit hash
- value = tag(s)

My script which I run in GIT dir:

```
#!/bin/sh
declare -A cc

echo "Fill 'cc' array:"
git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/tags | while read key value; do
  cc[$key]="${cc[$key]}${cc[$key]:+ }$value";
  echo "$key -> ${cc[$key]}"
done

echo "Print 'cc' array:"    
for ii in "${!cc[@]}"; do 
  echo "$ii -> ${cc[$ii]}"; 
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./cleaning.sh
Fill 'cc' array:
b41d8a63cb6434e76849a528604bd736458af839 -> 2014-07-30.v1
7b6b1523ff0bab428cb0fc65dc9249ae11a0dc52 -> 2014-08-13.v1
~
~
28dcd96836ce20773d046d49fa2e096245e6f6fa -> PRO SSPBE-9.6
e4b31b5fb541dd409d08e0a0b961f56e9e70821e -> SSPBE-9.7
Print 'cc' array:
$
```

First 'echo' in while loop works right and prints key and value(s). But then is run 'for' loop which should print list 'cc' to stdout but prints nothing. It looks like associative array 'cc' is empty.

---

### EDIT

I see where is problem with subshell. But If I use this syntax:

```
echo "Fill 'cc' array:"
while read k v; do
  cc[$k]="${cc[$k]}${cc[$k]:+ }$v";
done < <(git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/tags)

echo "Print 'cc' array:"
for ii in "${!cc[@]}"; do echo "$ii -> ${cc[$ii]}"; done
```

So I get:

```
$ ./cleaning.sh
Fill 'cc' array:
./cleaning.sh: line 39: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./cleaning.sh: line 39: `done < <(git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/tags)'
```

Interesting when I run it from command line so it finished successfully.

```
$ while read k v; do cc[$k]="${cc[$k]}${cc[$k]:+ }$v"; done < <(git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/tags)
$ for ii in "${!cc[@]}"; do echo "$ii -> ${cc[$ii]}"; done
164b1d93ee2f728e92be8d39aace814799c10a00 -> SSPBE-7.17 SSPBE-7.17
303c0deb4f32d224b28a305d54125b788f5ac75a -> SSPBE-7.21 SSPBE-7.21
~
```

---

### EDIT 2 - FIXED

Solved - I had to fix redirection:

```
 while read k v; do
  cc[$k]="${cc[$k]}${cc[$k]:+ }$v";
done <<< "$(git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/tags)"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13233452/1030675

Comment: Understand, thx. ;]  I changed script to `while ...; do _some_commands; done < <(git)` and have problem with script.

Comment: Ask a new question then (you might link to this one as a reference).